# UI Calendar AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, calendar

Using this UI Calendar on Angular JS, and it worked ok with the sample I got from their website, but when I put it inside of '.success' function (right after the alert on code below) returned form ajax it doesn't work, any ideas what may be wrong?

```
    $http.get(serverURL)
    .success(function(json) {
        alert('sss');

    });

    $scope.events = [{"event_id":"8","title":"hey - PUBLIC","name":"hey","date":"2015-11-13","className":"btn-info","allDay":true}];


    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function(view,calendar) {
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView',view);
    };
    /* Change View */
    $scope.renderCalender = function(calendar) {
        if(uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]){
            uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
        }
    };

        $scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) {
            element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
            $compile(element)($scope);
        };

        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar:{
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header:{
                    right: 'prev,next'
                },
                dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
                eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
                eventRender: $scope.eventRender
            }
        };

    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Comment: Maybe it failed. Do you see any errors on browser console?

Comment: Actually doesn't show any errors on browser. It shows the calendar but not the events.